# How to use only company local nexus repository

Tags: maven

I would like to create company local maven repository using nexus. Repository should not download anything from public internet, everything needed is added to repo. Developer's local maven instanses should download needed libraries and tools from company nexus. I have managed to do this by using mirror like this in settings.xml:

```
<mirror>
  <id>company-repository</id>
  <name>Company releases repository</name>
  <url>http://nexus.company.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```

Problem with this solution is that I am only able to point to releases repository, I would like to include thirdparty and snapshot repository to search as well. Has anyone any idea how that should be done? Mirror tag takes only one url.

I also tried with defining default profile like this:

```
<profile>            
    <id>defaultProfile</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>company-thirdparty-repo</id>
            <url>http://nexus.company.com//nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
            <releases>
                 <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy> 
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>company-releases-repo</id>
            <url>http://nexus.company.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://nexus.company.com/nexus/content/repositories/central</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>            
</profile>
```

Problem with that solution is that if Maven don't find something from those repositories it still downloads it from repo.maven.apache.org. I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use combination of both:

Create a repository group for the proxies of remote public repo (assume you call it public).  Use this to mirror the only default repository of Maven, which is "central"

For other repositories, just add it as repository/plugin repo

the settings.xml looks like this:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://your/nexus/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <!-- for you to override settings of central -->
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://a.fake.host</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>anotherRepo</id>
                    <url>http://your/nexus/groups/anotherRepo</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>

            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <!-- for you to override settings of central -->
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://a.fake.host</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>

                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>anotherRepo</id>
                    <url>http://your/nexus/groups/anotherRepo</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories> 
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: In the <mirrorOf> tag you need to say "*" otherwise only central will be mirrored (take a look here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html).

Comment: @khmarbaise That's what I am trying to do: Mirror central with on nexus repo group, and add additional repos on top of it

Comment: To solve this it should be configured in Nexus and not configured in settings.xml.

Comment: How it should be configured to nexus?

Comment: @khmarbaise You can do so, but configuring in settings.xml should also works, and both have its pros and cons.  For example, in case you have different repository combination for different teams, if doing in your way, you will need to setup different repository group for each team, while using my way, it is just a matter of configuration of putting the combination in settings.xml.  Not to mention the case that we may want to avoid access to snapshots for release build server, that will bloat number of repository groups in your way.  I am not saying my way is better but it is a matter of choice

Comment: And, just to share my experience, sometimes when I need to try out something new, I may need to add some new remote repositories.  However I don't want it to publicize (included in the globally shared nexus repository group) until I finish my tests.  Using my suggested way allows ease of configuration in such situation.